# assert.isBoolean is not passing for tinyint

Tags: javascript, mysql, mocha.js, chai

I am storing a boolean as a tinyint in mySQL. I am testing the return value as a boolean using:

```
assert.isBoolean(myTinyIntField);
```

and I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected 0 to be a boolean
```

Do I just need to test to see if it is 0 or 1? I thought that tinyint was equivalent to boolean. Perhaps that is not true in javascript context.

Comment: [it's very much not a boolean](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: _"`BOOL`, `BOOLEAN`: These types are synonyms for `TINYINT(1)`. A value of zero is considered `false`. Nonzero values are considered `true`"_ ([Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html))

Comment: In JavaScript `typeof myTinyIntField === 'number'` so, no, not a Boolean.